# Using Distinct and Count

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Count + Distinct]

Help me, please, how to use `Distinct` and `Count` keywords together.
To use `Distinct` on `columnA` and `Count` on `columnB`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `group by` instead of `distinct`:

```
select columnA
,      count(columnB)
from   tableX
group
by     columnA
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you want GROUP BY, but in case someone find this by question later and really does want COUNT and DISTINCT together...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT fld) 
  FROM tbl
```

That would be the traditional combination of the two and give you the number of distinct NOT NULL values for fld.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want.

Do you want to use Distinct and Count together?

Try this `SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(*)) FROM your_table`

But I think a `GROUP BY` will help you...

[See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)